# VLC player, Windows 7 pro

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player

The player is working fine except when the video changes. It is not showing the video title, I fixed that. It is popping the controls up between each video change. How can I stop that?

Answer (score 0):

- In VLC, under *Tools | *Preferences*, select *Video*.
- Check the *Fullscreen vidoe output* option.
- Click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button.

Viola, it should now play as you want!

[image: VLC Advance Preferences]